# Creating A UI Window For My Previous Script

Tags: python, user-interface, input, window, maya

folks!  So, thanks to you guys I was able to figure out what it was I was doing wrong in my previous script of staggering animation for selected objects in a scene.  I am now on part two of this little exercise: Creating a UI for it.

This involves creating a window with a button and user input of how much the animation will be staggered by.  So, instead of me putting how much the stagger should increment by (which was two in my previous script), I'd now allow the user to decide.

The script I have so far created the window, button, and input correctly, though I am having some trouble with getting the UI to properly execute, meaning when I click on the button, no error pops up; in fact, nothing happens at all to change the scene.  I get the feeling it's due to my not having my increment variable in the correct spot, or not utilizing it the right way, but I'm not sure where/how exactly to address it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have (with suggested edits) is as follows:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

spheres = cmds.ls(selection=True)

stagWin = cmds.window(title="Stagger Tool", wh=(300,100))
cmds.columnLayout()
button = cmds.button(label="My Life For Aiur!")
count = cmds.floatFieldGrp(fieldgroup, query=True, value=True)
fieldgroup = cmds.floatFieldGrp(numberOfFields=1)
cmds.button(button, edit=True, command=lambda _:stagger(fieldgroup))
cmds.showWindow(stagWin)

def stagger(fieldgroup):
    for i in spheres:
        cmds.selectKey(i)
        cmds.keyframe(edit=True, relative=True, timeChange=count)
    print "BLAH"
```

Comment: does stagger get called if you add a `print` statement to it?

Comment: also you're not querying floadFieldGrp correctly, and not saving that value anywhere

Comment: When adding "print stagger()", I get a "None" value.  Not sure if that's what you meant.  And would I still need to add a query value?  I wasn't sure that was necessary even for something supposedly as simple as this.  :x

Comment: what I meant was a `print "I'm alive!"` inside your stagger def. To query you need something like `count = cmds.floatFieldGroup(query=True, value=True)`

Comment: Tried it, window popped up per usual, tried getting it to run by clicking button, and an error popped up saying "No object name specified" inside the floatFieldGrp.  As for the print statement, nothing printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the comments into an answer because I think I've got it all figured out finally:

First of all, the better practice is to pass the stagger object to the button command rather than the string. so that would be:

```
cmds.button(label="My Life For Aiur!", command=stagger)
```

Secondly, the count isn't getting updated, so it stays `0` as per your third line. To update that:

```
count = cmds.floatFieldGrp(fieldgroup, query=True, value=True)
```

But wait, where did `fieldgroup` come from? We need to pass it into the function. So go back to your button code and take out the command entirely, also saving the object to a variable:

```
button = cmds.button(label="My Life For Aiur!")
```

Now store the object for the fieldgroup when you make it:

```
fieldgroup = cmds.floatFieldGrp(numberOfFields=1)
```

Now that you have fieldgroup, you can pass that in the function for the button, like this:

```
cmds.button(button, edit=True, command=lambda _:stagger(fieldgroup))
```

I had to wrap the function in a lambda because we're passing fieldgroup, but if I just put `stagger(fieldgroup)` it would call that and pass the result of that into the command for the button

Also update stagger def with fieldgroup argument:

```
def stagger(fieldgroup):
```

One final note that won't actually affect this, but good to know:

when you shift the keyframes inside `stagger` you're using a DIFFERENT count variable than the one you declared as `0` up above. The outer one is `global`, and the inner is `local` scope. Generally it's best to avoid global in the first place, which fortunately for you means just taking out `count = 0`

---

**Putting that all together:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

spheres = cmds.ls(selection=True)

stagWin = cmds.window(title="Stagger Tool", wh=(300,100))
cmds.columnLayout()
button = cmds.button(label="My Life For Aiur!")
fieldgroup = cmds.floatFieldGrp(numberOfFields=1)
cmds.button(button, edit=True, command=lambda _:stagger(fieldgroup))
cmds.showWindow(stagWin)

def stagger(fieldgroup):
    count = 0
    increment = cmds.floatFieldGrp(fieldgroup, query=True, value=True)[0]
    print count
    for i in spheres:
        cmds.selectKey(i)
        cmds.keyframe(edit=True, relative=True, timeChange=count)
        count += increment
    print "BLAH"
```

Comment: Your help is so much appreciated!  Unfortunately, now I'm back at the problem of, nothing is happening.

I will update the code above to show what I now have using your suggestions.  Is it due to one float being in the wrong place?  Like, should the count float variable be inside the function, instead?

Comment: You're editing the button in the wrong place. What I meant was after you've stored `fieldgroup`, edit `button` on the very next line, giving it the command you can now build knowing `fieldgroup`.

Comment: I edited the code above again.  Came across yet another error now: "Object 'window1|columnLayout14|floatFieldGrp3' not found."  The window "object", I'm guessing, has already been declared and called to show.  Not sure what it is that's going wrong now.

Comment: Edited with working code. Compare mine against what you have and maybe it'll click

Comment: Well, it did successfully stagger the animation for all of the spheres, that's halfway to where I want to go!  Now, the next step to be taken is to have it so the stagger is incremented.  Like, the first sphere would move, then the next would be staggered by the number input, and the next would be staggered from the one that was just staggered, so on and so forth.  And, I'm sorry for being a super newb when it comes to this kind of stuff, I know my questions might seem very simple-minded, but what is the point of having the "count" variable bracketed at the end?

Comment: It was returning a list, so the [0] takes the first element of the list. as for the stagger not working, take a look at your other question. something is missing from this implementation...

Comment: Well, the only logical thing I can come up with that's missing is the "+=" sign, but I thought that was only allowed to be used with numerical values (otherwise I'd have count += fieldgroup).  Everything else, with the exception of "count=0", as far as I can see, is already implemented.

Comment: you aren't incrementing count here. What you should do is start with `count = 0`, set another variable `increment = cmds.floatFieldGrp...`, and inside your `for` loop add `count += increment`

Comment: See, I knew I needed that operation, but I had no idea how I'd implement it because I had no idea it could be used with two variables, I always kept getting the error that it was expecting numerical units.  I think what also threw me off was that, since you suggested to take out "count=0", I thought there would have been another way to have "count".  But this is great, thank you so much, you've been amazing help!